# Why does this Azure function project generate the error: The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I am trying to run an azure function locally that uses a Service Bus Trigger.

I keep getting this error when I run the app locally:

> The binding type(s) 'serviceBusTrigger' are not registered. Please
> ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.

I have been [following the guidelines from this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus) about using Nuget to install Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus v 4.1.2 and I can confirm it is installed in my Solution Explorer as shown.

[image]

I am using Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2912)

Given that I've installed the required package, I don't understand why I continue to get the above error.

I have noticed that since this project has an Output Type of Class Library (and it targets .NET Stanard 2.0), it doesn't have a References node in the Project hierarchy.  As such, although the Nuget package is installed, I cannot seem to explicitly add a reference to it.  Would that be the cause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delete** the package and run `func extensions install`  to re-add all extension packages required in your local project.

It seems there are some difference between versions, you can update the version or use [extension bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles). About the format of Service Bus Trigger, follow this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp).